# What are the differences between 衣類, 衣服 and 服

Tags: word-choice

While I see 衣類 and　衣服 as more general concepts in comparison to 服, I am very unsure of the difference between them.

What situations explicitly call for one over the other? In what situations are both or all three acceptable?

Comment: A native speaker on this site recently mentioned that 衣類 was the normal word to refer to clothes but there does not seem to be a lot of difference in meaning. Possibly 衣服 is more formal?

Comment: What about `服装`?

Comment: I haven't stumbled upon that one before

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shogakukan's J-J *Ruigo Reikai Thesaurus Dictionary* has this to say about usage differences for **衣服** and **衣類**.

- 「衣服」は、主に外側に着る上着、ズボン、羽織の類についていう。
  *Ifuku* refers mostly to things like overcoats, trousers, and *haori* worn as outerwear.
- 「衣類」は、帯、靴下、肌着などまで含めて体に着けるものすべてに対する総称。
  *Irui* is a more general term that refers to all things that can be worn on the body, including *obi*, socks, and underwear.

Just plain old **服** isn't included in the same thesaurus entry, appearing instead under the entry for 洋服 ("western clothes").  Notably, 服 here in the thesaurus is glossed as "a dress" rather than "clothes", and the brief Japanese definition given in the thesaurus as common to both 洋服 and 服 states:

- 和服に対して、西洋風の衣服。
  Contrasting with traditional Japanese clothing, western-style outerwear.

The JA-JA dictionary I have says:

1. ころも。着物。衣服。
   Robes.  Kimono.  Outerwear.
2. 「洋服」の略。
   Short for "western clothing".

As a further data point, the usage examples in Shogakukan's *Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary* entry for 服 almost all suggest that 服 may imply more of a set outfit.  Here are a few excerpted examples (emphasis mine):

- 戦闘服の兵士たち　 soldiers in battle **dress**
- 道化師の服　 a clown's **costume**
- 結婚式の服〔男性の〕 a wedding **suit** / 〔女性の〕 a wedding **dress**
- 警察官の服　 a policeman's **uniform**
- 彼は紺の服が似合う　 The navy blue **suit** becomes him.

**服装** meanwhile has its own thesaurus entry, but the section about usage discusses only 装い in detail.  The English gloss for 服装 is given as "dress; costume", while the brief Japanese definition states:

- 衣服およびその装飾品などを身につけた姿。
  Appearance when wearing outerwear and other accessories.

Comment: Just FYI: I almost did not read your answer, it was so long. The part up to "The JA-JA" was enough for me (and useful because you were giving information not avaialble in English.)

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer, solved a lot of questions i had :)