# The different words for clothes

Tags: word-choice

There are several different words for “clothing” in the dictionary. Kimono is a type of traditional Japanese clothing, while fuku refers to Western clothes. Hifuku is more general and covers all clothing. Koromo is a less commonly used word than the others.

At least I think this is right based on what I read in the dictionary. Are these definitions right, and are there other words that also mean “clothes”?

Comment: Some of the same words covered https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15939/what-are-the-differences-between-%e8%a1%a3%e9%a1%9e-%e8%a1%a3%e6%9c%8d-and-%e6%9c%8d

Answer (score 6):

- **服**: The most neutral, generic, daily word for clothes.
- **衣服**: Formal version of 服. 「衣服のお手入れ」「世界の衣服の歴史」
- **洋服**: (Western) clothes we normally wear. It's almost synonymous to 服 in ordinary people's daily life. 「洋服売り場」
- **和服**: Japanese clothes (including *kimono*, *hakama*, *samue*, ...)
- **衣装**: Costume (for stage performances, role playing, etc), dress (the kind of outfits that celebrities wear in public) 「ステージ衣装」「コスプレ用の衣装」
- **着物**: Originally referred to clothes in general, but this usually refers to that Japanese formal *kimono* today.
- **お召し物**: Honorific word for 服.
- **被服**: Basically an even more formal or academic version of 衣服, but strictly speaking 被服 also includes shoes, hats, gloves and such.
- **衣**: Archaic word for 服 (especially simple ones) or coats. Used mainly in samurai films or hardcore fantasy.
- (**ドレス**: Almost exclusively refers to formal party dress for ladies.)

Note that 被服 and 衣 are definitely not words you would use in everyday life.

The above words are "wearable" (i.e., you can say ～を着る).

- **衣料品**/**衣類**: Daily clothing/underwear as merchandise or physical objects. 「スーパーの衣料品売り場」「衣類部門の売り上げ」
- **服装**: Overall outfit one is wearing. 「派手な服装をしている」「服装が乱れている」「事件当時の彼の服装」
- **服飾**: Fashion/dressmaking as a field of business/expertise 「服飾専門学校」「服飾店」
- **アパレル**: Loanword version of 服飾. 「アパレルショップ」「アパレル関係の店で働く」

Comment: OPのHifuku (被服) が抜けてます…

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth ありがとうございます、追記しました